# How to test proprietary network protocol

Tags: testing, automated-tests, test-environments, test-framework

I have a system I want to test, the system handles a proprietary network protocol (this need to be checked). The tested protocols are over TCP and UDP.

I'm looking for a software I could install on my OS-X/Linux/Windows computer connect it to the system I want to test and inject protocol messages and analyse feedback (software should have the ability to compare for each received message if it is the expected one etc.).

Prefer a software with a nice looking GUI and open-source so I could add features if needed (could be a paid software).

Where should I begin?

Answer (score 0):

There is a probably a library/framework which implements the protocol. My approach would be to use it (or write it when it's missing) to write simply unit tests.

There are many unit testing frameworks with nice GUIs, headless modes and automated tools, so unless you can be more specific, it's hard to suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

With the Argos protocol analyzer (http://xpro.co/index.php/products/argos), you can:

- define your proprietary protocol in XML
- monitor IP traffic, offload to TCP/UDP endpoints, load proprietary
  format text/binary logfiles
- visualize the analysis
- send commands/messages from command forms, where you can include also
  a COM/ActiveX control, which can generate and receive traffic and
  implement the logic behind it

Argos runs on Windows and it is a paid software.

Answer (score 0):

Using Load Multiplier (loadmultiplier.com), you can test proprietary protocols. Any text / binary call flows (with / without media) over any transport protocol like (udp / tcp / tls / dtls / sctp / websocket / secured websocket) can be simulated using multiplier.

Disclaimer: I work for load multiplier tool.